# How to avoid /remove overlapping table layout over number input keypad in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using table layout in my android form where this table layout having scroll bar
but of fix length of height. Table layout having EditText to enter data which allows to enter only number field .Number key  pad getting overlapped over height of table so I cant scroll to last record to see the input data how to avoid such over lapping ?

Image for  Table structure 
[image]
In mobile Actually

[image: Check overlapped keybord on my table layout]

```
    <ScrollView style="@style/TblScrollView" >

        <!-- Table Data section -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblOrdrPrdData"
            style="@style/ScrollableTblStyle" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<style name="ScrollableTblHdrStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
  <style name="ScrollableTblStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you send a picture? I couldn't understand the problem from what you said.

Comment: yes ..going to upload give few minutes

Comment: @holandaGo u can check now

Comment: Please, show your layout code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using property
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` shows what and where user is typing specially for end of table row

Answer (score 1):

You can set the windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize and it should not leave the screen, or, as google puts it:

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

As you need the Add button for your Activity to work, the most recommended is to resize, although there are other options. To do that you just need to add this to your Manifest (in the activity that you want that behavior):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Here's the Handling Input Method Visibility guide from AD: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

For more information on windowSoftInputMode:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Thanks for your effort .. but property adjustPan to see what and where user is typing specially for end of table row ...